# How to apply a backtracking algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm doing some excercises in Python course and one of them where I'm stuck is below:

```
Given a digit sequence that represents a message where each uppercase letter 
is replaced with a number (A - 1, B - 2, ... , Z - 26) and space - 0. 
Find the number of the initial messages, from which that sequence 
could be obtained.

Example: 12345 - 3 (ABCDE, LCDE, AWDE)
         11 - 2 (AA, K)
```

The naive solution is easy and it is simple bruteforce algorithm:

```
import string

def count_init_messages(sequence):
    def get_alpha(seq):
        nonlocal count

        if len(seq) == 0:
            count += 1
            return

        for i in range(1, len(seq) + 1):
            if seq[:i] not in alph_table:
                break
            else:
                get_alpha(seq[i:])

    alphabet = " " + string.ascii_uppercase
    # generate dictionary of possible digit combination
    alph_table = {str(n): alph for n, alph in zip(range(len(alphabet)), alphabet)}
    # counter for the right combination met
    count = 0
    get_alpha(sequence)

    return count

def main():
    sequence = input().rstrip()
    print(count_init_messages2(sequence))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But as the length of an input sequence might be as long as 100 characters and there might be lots of repetition I have met a time limits. For example, one of the sample input is `2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 (possible messages number is 308061521170129)`. As my implementation makes too many repetition it takes ages for processing such an input. I think of using the backtracking algorithm, but I haven't realised yet how to implement the memoization for the succesive results.

I'd be glad if it is possible to point me out to the right way how to break that task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recurrence relation you have to solve (where `s` is a string of digits, and `a` and `b` are single digits) is this:

```
 S("") = 1
 S(a) = 1
 S(s + a + b) = S(s+a) + (S(s) if ab is between 10 and 26)
```

That can be computed using dynamic programming rather than backtracking. If you do it right, it's O(n) time complexity, and O(1) space complexity.

```
def seq(s):
    a1, a2 = 1, 1
    for i in xrange(1, len(s)):
        a1, a2 = a1 + (a2 if 9 < int(s[i-1:i+1]) < 27 else 0), a1
    return a1

print seq('2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222')
```

Comment: it seems broken for `12345` input

Comment: @Ashot -- thanks, you're right. The indexing was off `[i-1:i]` should have been `[i-1:i+1]`. Fixed now.

Comment: @PaulHankin, thank you for the idea but it won't work for input `11101`. Your code gives output `2` while the right answer with mine is `5`. Should the sum be accumulated somehow in a different way?

Comment: Ah, I missed that "0" can stand alone as a space. It's a simple fix -- that makes the code a little simpler. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The largest number in the lookup table is 26 so you never need to lookup strings of lengths greater than 2. Modify the for loop accordingly. That might be enough to make brute force viable.

Comment: I tried to fix the `for` loop inside the `get_alpha` function and get sequentially not more than two digits, but it doesn't work here. Checking in a dictionary efficiently breaks if a current taken number is greater than 27.

Comment: `seq[:i]` means "the list up to and not including `seq[i]`". For example, when you get to `10` the program will generate `seq[1:10]`. Only check `seq[i]` and `seq[i:i+1]`

Comment: `if seq[:i] not in alph_table` seems to be the culprit. Try something like `if seq[i] not in alph_table && seq[i:i+1] not in alph_table:`

Comment: @David as you can see on each step there is a check for a `seq` whether the digits in the dictionary or not. And to the next recursion tree level he passes sliced sequence.

Comment: That's not the issue. Your code is slow because you use `seq[:i]` when you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

You may have also recognized 308061521170129 as the 71st Fibonacci number. This relationship corresponds with the Fibonacci numbers giving "the solution to certain enumerative problems. The most common such problem is that of counting the number of compositions of 1s and 2s that sum to a given total n: there are Fn+1 ways to do this" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics).

Every contiguous subsequence in the string that can be divided into either single or double digit codes represents such an `n` with multiple possible compositions of 1s and 2s; and thus, for every such subsequence within the string, the result must be multiplied by the (subsequence's length + 1) Fibonacci number (in the case of the 70 2's, we just multiply 1 by the 71st Fibonacci number).